# Is there any possible method to track geographical location of blocks and transactions in ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any way I could find the location of the sender and receiver of a transaction through sender and receiver's ID (i.e 0x0000000103026f36d9f2ba6468d2816cd5dce83a) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "location?"

Answer (score 2):

The protocol doesn't provide any means for tracking ips or geographical locations of blocks and transactions.

You could launch Ethereum nodes evenly across the globe, make sure their clocks are synchronized, and keep track of the ip addresses of the nodes from which you receive transactions and the corresponding timestamps.

Collect all of this data in a central database; given a particular transaction, pick the entry with the earliest timestamp. The ip address inside this entry is the closest to the one from which the transaction originated.